# Vue make ES6 class object reactive

Tags: vuejs2, es6-class

I have a ES6 class that I use to hold and manage datas:

```
import DataManager from "./components/data-manager.js";
export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      dataModel: null
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.dataModel = new DataManager();
  },
  computed: {
    datas() {
      return this.dataModel.myProperty
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

But it appears that there is a reactivity issue and any changes made into that `dataModel` does not trigger the re-rendering of the view. 
How can I make the properties of my class reactive ?

Thanks,

**Edit:** @acdcjunior The Class looks like this, but I realize that some mutation occurs... would that be the issue ? Anyway if thats not good practice to make a whole ES6+ class reactive, I'll get ride of that and go for a plain Object, or even Vuex store. Any simple suggestion ?

```
class DataManager {
  constructor() {
    this.professionalsList = [];
    this.eventsList = [];
    this.attendeesList = [];    
  }

  // import datas
  importDatas({
    professionalsList,
    eventsList,
    attendeesList
  }) {
    this.professionalsList = this.parsePros(professionalsList)
    ... 
  }
  parsePros(list) {
    return list.map( item => { ... })
  }
  ...
}
```

Edit #2: So the issue was indeed some mutations that occures in one of the objects I was trying to bind.

Comment: Can you show the code for `DataManager`? Thought not advised ([data should be plain objects](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data)), Vue does support reactivity for classes.

Comment: @acdcjunior I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the same data structure in data().dataModel as returned from DataManager() and change every property in methods. When you setting new dynamic property in data object they can't be reactive. You can try Vue.set(), but it's a bad practice.